# Is this correct (JavaScript prototype property)?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

Here I created a function which will ultimately be used as a constructor for other clones. Aside from the properties `arguments, caller, length, name, __proto__(link to Function.protoype)` created, the `prototype` property is created. This property points to the object which will be assigned as the prototype to the instances created when this function is invoked when using the `new` keyword.

```
function Clonetrooper(ID, rank, yearsOfService, type){
if (!(this instanceof Clonetrooper)){
    return new Clonetrooper(ID, rank, yearsOfService, type);
}
this.ID = ID;
this.rank = rank;
this.yearsOfService = yearsOfService;
this.type = type;
}
```

So when I do this:

```
Clonetrooper.prototype.hasUtilityBelt = true;
Clonetrooper.prototype.hasLightSaber = false;
```

I am adding properties on the `Clonetrooper` prototype property. One by one.

But if I do **this** afterwards:

```
Clonetrooper.prototype = {
    name: null
    hasDroid: null

};
```

I have overwritten the link to the `Clonetrooper's` constructor replacing it with a new `Object` which links to Object.prototype.

So my question is, that last syntax is indeed overwriting your `prototype` property?

So probably one should carefully plan out a `object` to avoid this occurrence.

Comment: Well, you are not wrong. Is there anything else you wanted to ask about?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Better yet: what is **the** question? (The only things that are questions are the title and out comments.)

Comment: Essentially!!!! At first I couldn't see when you use that syntax you are basically making a new object rather than creating a shorthand to expedite property creation.

Comment: If the question is to understand why that is, then a good start would be reading Ch. 5 of [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md).

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz When you don't know a prototype, try this: `({}).__proto__`. Replace `{}` with whatever value you wish. (May not work in IE) or `Object.getPrototypeOf()` (Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Comment: THANKS Jason! @Ismael Oui, laLa! THANKS i'll have to check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we must be careful. In most cases we should *extend* the **existing** prototype  by one of two ways:

```
Clonetrooper.prototype.foo = ...
```

or (e.g. using jQuery)

```
$.extend(Clonetrooper.prototype, {
    bar: ...,
    baz: ...
})
```

Comment: Shows how much I know `jQuery` I didn't know it had such functions to help in that way, I thought it was all `DOM` related. But I guess in the end most things are? Thank you!

Comment: jQuery has a lot of helpful functionalities :) learn it if you want to ease your coding. Learning of source code of popular frameworks is a good practice.

Comment: Indeed, I'll put that on my todo list!